# How do I force the aurelia-cli to ignore html bundling?

Tags: aurelia

Eisenberg already tried to help me with this issue, but admitted he really didn't know how to do it either: https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss?at=586dd660aa6be0472f0c608d

When running the aurelia-cli with `au run` it auto-bundles the app and during that process we tried to remove the html processing, however in the end, the closest we were to getting the bundle to look for the html pages on the server was an `app-bundle.html` page that obviously isn't created and shouldn't exist.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated as my development is halted until I can get this sorted out.

Comment: If you want to use jade templates I would strongly consider using a more feature-rich and configurable setup as opposed to the CLI which currently handles some basic things well but you are entering a territory of wanting lots of configuration.

Comment: @PWKad What would you suggest? The whole reason for switching to Aurelia CLI is to get away from SystemJS as it's become exceedingly slow, not to mention I prefer the bundle-on-save functionality of the Aurelia-cli. Getting away from JSPM was also nice.

Comment: @PWKad "...entering a territory of wanting lots of configuration..." this isn't true at all. I think being able to choose whether I want html bundled or not is hardly difficult configuration and was in fact, an option of the original bundling mechanism which was done through JSPM/SystemJS. It should be as simple as excluding a property or setting one flag, as it was with JSPM/SystemJS. I'm essentially wanting **less** configuration, because I want to exclude html bundling.